# How to make a text file "Open With" my Win Api Text Editor?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, text

I have recently made a small text editor in C WinApi. Ive almost done everything but I cant figure out how to make text files open with my program. The WinMain function does not have argc and *argv[] parameters like the normal C main function. So how do I get Cmd input?

Answer (score 1):

Use the WinAPI GetCommandLine.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have tried using the GetCommandLine and CommandLineToArgvW functions I cant get them to work. Can anyone post an example?

Comment: I've given you a link to documentation.  It returns the command line string.